# If I install a new ROM does that erase all my installed apps and dat?

Tags: updates, root-access

If I have a rooted (Razr M in this case) and want to install an updated ROM (e.g., to upgrade to a new 'Droid OS version) will I need to reinstall my apps and restore my data?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Unless you wipe all your data before the update, you do not need to Reinstall applications or Restore application data. But when flashing a completely different new ROM, it's recommended to do a full wipe before proceed. Further more, If you are planing to do a full wipe you can use a application like [My Backup Pro](https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=com.rerware.android.MyBackupPro&hl=en) or [Titanium Backup](https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=com.keramidas.TitaniumBackup&hl=en) to back up all your applications and data.